# LINQ to EF - Simulating SQL "IN" clause

Tags: .net, linq

I read some great tips here regarding getting decent SQL to be generated from LINQ to EF.  The LINQ query below is what I came up with.  (I formulated the following LINQ query based on existing code that I am now augmenting, plus tips from this forum.)

The resulting SQL being captured shows that the WHERE clause is using a bunch of successive ORs, rather than an IN.  Is there a way to force this translation to IN?

```
      string[] circuits = circuitIDList.ToArray();
       using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
        {
            var q = from n in ctx.v_myview
                    where circuits.Contains(n.circuitid)
                    select n;

            string tSQL = q.ToTraceString();

            return q.ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no way of providing "hints" to the Linq query provider of how you want your Linq statement to be translated - this is totally up to the provider. In this case the provider might decide on a particular mapping (WHERE .. IN vs OR) for one reason or another (i.e. performance), but both are *logically* equivalent.

Having said that, both queries actually do result in the same execution plan (at least for SQL server), so performance wise it should not make a difference.